# If a final static integer variable can't be changed in java, why in Calendar class, DATE can be changed?

Tags: java, final

As far as I know, a final static primitive instance variable cannot be changed in java. However when I look into ***java.util.Calendar***, I find these lines of code:

```
public final static int DATE = 5;
```

and I can manipulate DATE like this

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);
```

I am a little lost. Why?

Comment: Are you really changing `DATE`? What do you think `add` does?

Comment: How about  c.set(Calendar.DATE, 30);

Comment: What do you think `set` does?

Comment: What do you think `DATE` represents? You've obviously found the source code, why don't you read the javadoc?

Comment: `Calendar.DATE` is used as an index in order to find the right field to edit in the `add` method. Callins this method does NOT modify the value of `DATE`. You should try to read the implementation of the method in the Calendar class.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer. Sorry for my carelessness.

Comment: The variable itself is not final; the reference is. That means you can alter the object a final variable references, but not the object it points to.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that "DATE" is final means you cannot change it after initialization
Calendar.DATE= 8 ; // fails

The code you showed (c.add...) changes the value of Calendar.time which is not final.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the document of Calendar class, I think the reason is this:

```
public final static int DATE = 5
```

defines a field index for DATE field for a array fields[] which contain all the time information for a Calendar instance. Here 5 menas fields[5] store the date information. This index cannot be changed, but we can use

```
set(Calendar.DATE, 10)
```

to change fields[DATE] into 10.

By the way, thanks for all the valuable and explicit answers.